# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ms-access

First of all, yes I know there are several other questions about this. I have reviewed and tried different solutions proposed in them; however I'm still getting a "Syntax error INSERT INTO statement" message when I click on the submit button to run the function.

I'm running VS 2015 and an Access 2010 db. The full error message is as follows:

> Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Syntax error in INSERT INTO
>   statement. at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult
>   hr) at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS
>   dbParams, Object& executeResult) at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object&
>   executeResult) at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method) at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at
>   createAcc.btnCreateAccount_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   e:\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\WebSites\OneStopFurniture\createAcc.aspx.cs:line 43

My code for the button handler is as follows:

```
protected void btnCreateAccount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=E:\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\WebSites\\OneStopFurniture\\App_Data\\OneStopFur.accdb";
    string InsertQuery;
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmdInsert = new OleDbCommand();
        cmdInsert.Connection = connection;

        InsertQuery= "INSERT INTO [userInfo] (
           userName, password, firstName, lastName, userAddress, userCity, userZip, userPhone, userEmail
        ) VALUES (
           @userName, @password, @firstName, @lastName, @userAddress, @userCity, @userState, @userZip, @userPhone, @userEmail
        )";
        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", txtUserName.Text);
        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);
        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", txtFirstName.Text);
        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", txtLastName.Text);
        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userAddress", txtAddress.Text);
        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userCity", txtCity.Text);
        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userState", txtState.Text);
        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userZip", txtZip.Text);
        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userPhone", txtPhone.Text);
        cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userEmail", txtEmail.Text);

        cmdInsert.CommandText = InsertQuery;
        cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
        lblConfirm.Visible = true;
        lblConfirm.Text = "Account creation successful.";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblConfirm.Visible = true;
        lblConfirm.Text = "Unable to create" + ex;

    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me what I am overlooking here? At this point, I'm at a complete lose.

Thanks.

Comment: 10 parameters 9 columns

Comment: Better query formatting would have helped you find this error yourself. Look at the change I made and how the target columns now line up somewhat with the values? It's MUCH easier to scan and compare, now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate error is caused by the word `Password`. This is a reserved keyword in MS-Access. Use square brackets around it.

```
InsertQuery= @"INSERT INTO [userInfo](userName, [password], firstName, 
  lastName, userAddress, userCity, userState, userZip, 
  userPhone, userEmail) 
  VALUES(@userName, @password, @firstName, 
  @lastName, @userAddress, @userCity, @userState, @userZip, 
  @userPhone, @userEmail)";
```

After fixing this error you need also to add the column UserState (or whatever is called) because you have added a parameter for it.

Keep in mind that in OleDb the parameters are positional. This means the the first field receives the value from the first parameter, whatever name you have used, so missing a field or inverting the position of a parameter in the collection could cause bugs very difficult to spot. Double your checks here.

Answer (score 4):

Missing **UserState** in column list.

```
InsertQuery= "INSERT INTO [userInfo]
            ([userName], [password], [firstName], [lastName], [userAddress], [userCity], [userState], [userZip], [userPhone], [userEmail])
     VALUES(@userName, @password, @firstName, @lastName, @userAddress, @userCity, @userState, @userZip, @userPhone, @userEmail)";
```

The good practise is to qoute everything to avoid collision with keywords.

Comment: @Steve You mean password keyword?

Comment: Yes, the Syntax Error is caused by the word Password, then the poster will get the error caused by the unexpected parameter.